# After compiling code with pointers, .cpp file turns into random characters

Tags: c++

I'm in a beginners c++ class and we are learning about pointers and pointer arithmetic. We were asked to use a function to create a new dynamic array and have the function output its pointer. However, whenever I compile it turns my .cpp file into a whole bunch of random characters. I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm just unaware of but I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int* create_array(int);

int main()
{
        int *dyn_array;
        int students;
        float avrg;

        do
        {
                cout << "How many students will you enter? ";
                cin >> students;
        }while ( students <= 0 );

        dyn_array = create_array( students );
                //this function creates a dynamic array
                //and returns its pointer
//        enter_data( dyn_array, students );
                //use 'pointer' notation in this function to
                //access array elements
                //accept only numbers 0-100 for movie seen
//        avrg = find_average( dyn_array, students );
                //use 'pointer' notation in this function to
                //access array elements


//        cout << "The array is:" << endl << endl;
//        show_array( dyn_array, students);

//        cout << endl;
//        cout << "The average is " << avrg << ".\n";

        delete [] dyn_array;
        return 0;
}

int* create_array(int f_students)
{
        int *dyn_array = new int[f_students];
        return dyn_array;
}
```

This is what my .cpp file turns into after I compile it:

```
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^O^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^F^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^M^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@N^@^@^@?$
^@^@ě^D^H^G^L^@^@ț^D^H^G^M^@^@̛^D^H^G^O^@^@U??^H?^@^@^@<^A^@^@G^C^@^@?^@5?^D^H%?^D^H^@^@^@^@%?^D^Hh^@^@^@^@???%?^D^Hh^H^@^@^@???%?^D^Hh
```

Comment: How are you compiling your program?

Comment: Did you run `gcc myFile.cpp -o myFile.cpp` or similar? `-o` option specifies the name of the output executable file, if you provide the same name as the input file, it will be overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. I was compiling it as c++ students_movies.cpp -o students_movies.cpp. The extra cpp at the end was totally messing me up. Thank you so much for calling out that it was probably an issue with how I was compiling it.

Comment: To avoid situations like this in the future, you can use `make students_movies` to compile and link `students_movies.cpp` using the default Make rule.